# Choose the Transport Layer Security protocol - requests python

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I am using using the following code to choose the transport layer security protocol while issuing a request to server. Could someone please review it.
This is in reference to the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657498/i-want-to-choose-the-transport-layer-security-protocol-in-urllib2

```
import ssl
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)


s = requests.Session()
myAdp = MyAdapter()
myAdp.init_poolmanager(5, 100)
s.mount('https://', myAdp)

try:
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    feed = s.get(url, verify = True)
    print feed.text
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e
```